# How to validate if array is not empty

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-validation

how can i validate of an array's object if array is not empty.

I have a multi-dimensional array which i have to validate using laravel validation rule but i am not be able to do that.

**Array**

```
$array = [

  "family" => [

    [
      "adult" => 2
      "kids" => [
        ["age" => 1]
      ]
    ]


    [
      "adult" => 3
      "kids" => [

      ]
    ]

    [
      "adult" => 2
      "kids" => [
        ["age" => 5]
        ["age" => 2]
      ]
    ]

  ]

]
```

I have to validate most of the `key-val` for example : `family` must be `array`, validate `adult` and `kids` if family is not empty (`adult` must be `numeric`, `kids` must be `array` and validate `age` if `kids` not empty (`age` must be `numeric`))

**What i have done so far :**

```
$request->validate([
      'family' => 'required|array|min:1',
      'family.*.adult' => 'required_if:?|numeric', //validate if family is not empty
      'family.*.kids' => 'required_if:?|array', //validate if family is not empty and it can be empty
      'family.*.kids.*.age' => 'required_if:?|numeric', //validate if kids is not empty
    ]);
```

what to do i am not be able to understand?

Comment: did you try .. the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)?

Comment: I have tried docs and it's very simple to do that way but what is the meaning of using [laravel-validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [validator.sometimes()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#conditionally-adding-rules) method to conditionally add validation rules:

```
use Validator;

$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'family' => 'required|array|min:1'
]);

$validator->sometimes('family.*.adult', 'required|numeric', function ($input) {
    return !empty($input->family);
});

// etc..

$validator->validate();
```

Comment: but how to validate age if kids are empty?